# How to use DataTable ReadXml to read small subsets of a large Xml file

Tags: .net, xml, datatable

I have an datatable serialized to Xml. It has 1000's of records. Using the DataTable's ReadXml method works, but it is very slow. I am only interested in the first 100 records. Is there a way of reading the file, extracting the first 100 records, and loading that using the ReadXml method?

Comment: sounds like a job for xpath selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this!

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load( "c:\\testfile2.xml" );
foreach (XmlNode nd in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes( "xml/entry" ))
{
...
}
```

im not up on dot net so this could be different..

also please look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998559.aspx

Comment: unfortunately, there is no performance benefit as doc.Load reads the entire file... I'm looking for some method where I can stream the file... i.e. read a bit of it, and add all the nodes in it to an in-memory object. when I have 100 nodes in my new document, stop loading.

Comment: Thanks for the link... Reading it, found out about XmlTextReader, and it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use one of the classes derived from [System.Xml.XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) to sequentially read the file rather than loading the entire file into memory.